# how to stop passing value to next process?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new beginner in react-native and JavaScript here, i am using a if-else condition.

i want to check the first the condition is correct if it's correct then it will works in a different different function.
Here is my codes:

```
const ab = true; 
let x;
if (ab === false){
    
// i want here to stop passing value of x;
//write a code so that x value can't be passed to console.log(x).

}
else if (ab=== true){
 x= [1,2,3]
}

console.log(x);
```

only when ab equals true, x value able to use.
anyone can help me to write a codes for if statement where it will stop to passing values when the condition is correct.

Thanks for your trying in advance!

Comment: Perhaps it is worth calling the variable in the function and isolating it there, if the condition is not met, then do not initialize the variable at all. If the condition is met, then you need to initialize the variable and pass it through the call to the function and pass the value of your variable with the function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new beginner in JavaScript.
maybe you can do like this:

```js
let x 
const ab = true
if (ab === false) {
    // do what you want
    return
} else if (ab === true) {
    x = [1, 2, 3]
}
console.log(x)
```

or like this:

```js
let x 
const ab = true
if (ab === false) {
    // do what you want
} else if (ab === true) {
    x = [1, 2, 3]
}
if (x != null && x != undefined) {
    console.log(x)
}
```

Comment: Your code for `if(x != null || x != undefined)` is always TRUE, use **AND** (&&) operator instead. Or just simply put the `console.log()` within `if( ab === true ){}`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically i wanted to try stop to pass value with a condition but later i tried only one condition and it was worked.

suppose,

```
const ab = true; 
let x;
if (ab=== true){
 x= [1,2,3]
}

console.log(x);
```

so in there if ab is true only that time it will give x values otherwise automatically it will stop. Thanks